# New EU-DSGVO 2018 - Is a new agreement necessary?

Tags: database

Dear CiviCRM beta team,

we as the NGO "Wissenschaftsladen hannover e.V" would like to know whether we need a new agreement concerning the new DSGVO (Datenschutzgrundverordnung). 
According to the new privacy policy, which will come into effect at may 25th 2018, a lot of laws will change and therefore our question revolves around future changes in terms of our general agreement and different new things we should consider.
An answer in german would be fine too / Eine Antwort auf deutsch wäre auch ok.

Yours faithfully, Wissenschaftsladen Hannover e.V
Denis Matthies

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there will be an easy answer to this GDPR question (also it is only party CiviCRM-related) but the following resources could be useful:

- https://www.fellowshipproductions.co.uk/make-your-website-gdpr-compliant/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation
- https://www.gdd.de/gdd-arbeitshilfen/praxishilfen-ds-gvo/praxishilfen-ds-gvo
  (coherent information in German lanaguage)

Also, you will be happy to know that there is a CiviCRM extension which focusses on the topic of GDPR / DSGVO: https://civicrm.org/blog/parvez/announcing-a-new-gdpr-extension